# Access Control on Hibernate Results in Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, filter, listener

I need to filter out some of the objects returned by the Hibernate depending on the access control of the user doing the search. And I want to do in database layer if possible. I am using Spring.

Scenario

User A is searching on Employee.class
User A gets 10 results
User A is suppose to get only 5 out of 10 results based on the access control

What I want to do is intercept the result and apply access control and remove 5 of the 10 results received and only show 5 to User A

Could you help.

Comment: What does your code look like? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [`PostFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) Annotation.  It is designed to filter the result of an method, based on security decisions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Spring Security (and even if you are) Hibernate Filters are another possible solution:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-data-filter-example-xml-and-annotation/